# Constructing a Cumulative Distribution Function using a multi-variable pdf

Tags: matlab, probability, bayesian, particle-filter

I am constructing 2 arbitrary PDFs (probability density functions) from a kernel function and representing them as 2 column vectors lets call them **A** and **B**.

Each of these pdf is dependant on each other and are a conditional sample of an unknown underlying pdf given information from a previous time step.

My goal is to create a surface of their joint pdf **P(A, B)** represented by the matrix 
(edit: due to @Roberts suggestions I'm a little unsure how to construct this now)

I want to then create a normalised (i.e. [0,1]) cumulative distribution function for this surface so I can randomly sample from the surface. (In Matlab)

In 2D it's simply a matter of computing the `cumsum` of the pdf i.e.

```
CDF_A = cumsum(A)
```

but in 3D I'm not 100% convinced that it's a matter of computing the `cumsum` in both directions i.e.

```
% Possible CDF
Surface = A'*B;
partial_integral = cumsum(Surface,1);
possible_CDF_surface = sumsum(partial_integral,2);
```

I was hoping **SO** would have some ideas.

Mathematically, I presume it is simply the bounded double integral (or surface integral) of the function.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In general, if A and B are dependent variables, you can sample from their joint distribution by sampling from the marginal distribution P(A) and then from the conditional distribution P(B | A) using the value of A which you got. (Remember that P(A, B) = P(A | B) P(B) = P(A) P(B | A).) It is not necessary to sample directly from the joint distribution, although I suppose it might or might not be more convenient in specific cases.

It appears that you are assuming that A and B are independent; you have assumed their joint distribution is just P(A) P(B). Therefore, all you have to do is sample A from its distribution and B from its distribution, separately. It is not necessary to construct P(A, B) and sample directly from that (as it must yield the exact same result).

Comment: Your completely right I have assumed independence (I have fixed my question). In fact they are very dependent and so that assumption was very incorrect.
I did consider the marginal distribution but I was unsure about how I would going about obtaining that particular distribution.
Maybe a little background would help clarify my question.
This particular implementation is part of a Particle Filter algorithm and the 2 distributions are constructed from samples of the underlying unknown function and constructed using a Kernel convolution (e.g. Epanechnikov Kernel)

Comment: @Chriso Well, if they are dependent then you sample P(A), then P(B | A) (or equivalently, P(B), P(A | B)). If you do not already have the conditional distribution (either P(A | B) or P(B | A)) then you are going to have to find it or approximate it or assume it somehow; given that A and B are not independent, you must have some expression of their dependence.